# Is it possible to wrap IMEs?

Tags: android, input, wrapper, ime

I'm fleshing out a program idea and have ran into a point I'm not sure about. I'm trying to write a new InputMethodService for Android which would add functionality to other services.

An example of what I'm trying to do is: I want to write a Speech-to-Text service and then feed the text into another 3rd party IME. This would then allow me to use the functionality of that IME. So if for example I'm speaking Japanese, I want to be able to convert to Chinese characters through the 3rd party IME.

I'm not exactly sure its doable though because the SDK mentions "Only one IME can be active at a time." It seems like once I call the setInputMethod and feed a new IME to it, my service would lose the ability to detect focus changes and calls to the IME (so as to know when it wants input).

Am I correct in my understanding of the documentation? Or is there possibly some other way to go about doing this?